# How to layout this GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I am creating a GUI in java. Currently i have an empty JFrame and am trying to add a JPanel to it. The JPanel contains buttons, text etc. However none of this is being properly displayed. My code is as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class memoDisplayUI { 


JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JTextArea jTextBox = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                memoDisplayUI frame = new memoDisplayUI();
                frame.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public memoDisplayUI() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {

    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 270, 400);
    frame.setUndecorated(true); //REMOVES MENU BAR
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel lblMemos = new JLabel("MEMOS");
    lblMemos.setForeground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
    lblMemos.setFont(new Font("Moire", Font.BOLD, 30));
    lblMemos.setBounds(16, 16, 234, 37);
    panel.add(lblMemos);

    JButton button = new JButton("");
    button.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
    button.setBounds(7, 350, 40, 40);
    panel.add(button);
    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("back.png"));

    JButton button_1 = new JButton("");
    button_1.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
    button_1.setBounds(113, 350, 40, 40);
    panel.add(button_1);
    button_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Edit.png"));

    JButton button_2 = new JButton("");
    button_2.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
    button_2.setBounds(220, 350, 40, 40);
    panel.add(button_2);
    button_2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("memo.png"));

    JButton btnExit = new JButton("");
    btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    btnExit.setBorder(null);
    btnExit.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Exit.jpg"));
    btnExit.setBounds(216, 19, 40, 40);
    panel.add(btnExit);

    jTextBox = new JTextArea();
    scroll.setViewportView(jTextBox); // add scroll panel
    jTextBox.setTabSize(4);
    jTextBox.setLineWrap(true);
    jTextBox.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 192));
    jTextBox.setBounds(8, 60, 255, 286);
    panel.add(jTextBox);

    frame.setContentPane(panel);
}
}
```

My desired layout is something very similar to this:

[image]

Could someone advise as to why this is.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: What do you mean by "... none of this is being properly displayed"? Are the elements not added to the frame? Are just not in the position you want them to be in?

Comment: I see `BorderLayout`, may be `GridBagLayout` and/or `GridLayout`

Comment: I gave you a hint in your last post. Basically you are adding the components to the panel which has a default flowlayout. You are trying to position all your components which won't work with a layout managers. Set your panel layout to null. Again I'll reiterate though, look into `LayoutManager` get some practice in by looking at AndrewThompsons answer to the question, and looking at [Laying out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: I see 2 x `BorderLayout` instances, one as an 'outer' layout for other components and layouts, the other in the `PAGE_START` (top) for the label and `X` button.  The text area, preferably wrapped in a `JScrollPane`, would go in the `CENTER` of the outer `BorderLayout`.  The `B/E/M` buttons would go in a single row `GridLayout` in the `PAGE_END` of the outer layout.  Add an `EmptyBorder` to the outer layout panel, throw in some padding in the layouts themselves, and it is done.

Comment: @mKorbel Wasn't playing to answer